# Can't generate pretty URLs in Owncloud

Tags: .htaccess, owncloud

In the [officiall documentation for Owncloud 9](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#proxy-configurations) it says:

```
'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',

To have clean URLs without /index.php this parameter needs to be configured.
After setting this value run occ maintenance:update:htaccess [...]
```

However, running "occ maintenance:update:htaccess" will result in an error:

```
There are no commands defined in the "maintenance:update" namespace.
```

Can I update my .htaccess file manually?

Answer (score 2):

I have just read on the #owncloud IRC at freenode.net that the maintenance:update:htaccess command will be available in the next minor version: 9.0.3

Apparently the documentation has been updated before the code itself.

In the meantime, you can indeed edit .htaccess yourself.

On my installation I would do:

`sudo nano /var/www/owncloud/.htaccess`

Then, in the last section of the file update the RewriteBase line to look like:

`RewriteBase /owncloud`